# How to build an in-memory tree from file representation

Tags: c++

I would like to load the following syntax as a `Decision` tree. I found [here](http://www.tnelson.demon.co.uk/mastermind/table.html) the description of an optimized table for MasterMind. Each Decision contains a guess and all potential next guess depending of the answer we get for the current. I decided to represent a Decision by:

```
class Decision
{
public:
    string guess;
    map<int, Decision> nextGuess;

    Decision() {}
    Decision(std::pair<string,map<int, Decision>> p) : guess(p.first), nextGuess(p.second) {}
};
```

Now I would parse the table but how can I achieve that. I can use boost and I'm looking to `spirit`to see if I can build a recursive parser, but for now all idea are welcome ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use boost::property_tree to parse the decision tree from a xml, ini or json representation.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/property_tree.html